# .times block not working. How come?

Tags: ruby

The line adding the exponentiation to result doesn't seem to be doing the trick. How come?

```
def pow(base, exponent)
    result = 0
    exponent.times do
        result += base * base
    end
    result
end
```

Comment: You're computing `exponent * base**2` here.  I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: You need to use `result = 1` instead of `result = 0`, and `result *= base` instead of `result += base * base`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think Patrice is right. OP's code is computing the sum from 0 to `exponent` of `base` squared. This is the same as `exponent * (base ** 2)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, what do you mean?

Comment: @PatriceGahide, Asad, what I meant to say was, "I think I messed that up a bit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The times block is working fine. In order to raise a base b to an exponent n, you need to multiply 1 by b n times.

```
def pow(base, exponent)
    result = 1
    exponent.times do
        result *= base
    end
    result
end
```